# gremlin query to filter list of list values to get true or false

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

```java
g.V("JobDefinition1").
  out("JobDependency").
  coalesce(out('JobDefinitionToJobHistory').has("Timestamp", between("2022-06-21T00:00:00Z", "2022-06-25T00:00:00Z")).has("Status", 2).values("Timestamp").fold(),
           constant("0001-00-00T00:00:00Z"))
```

I have a gremlin query like above, then I will get a result like below.

```
[
  [
    "2022-06-21T00:00:00Z",
    "2022-06-23T00:00:00Z"
  ],
  [
    "2022-06-20T00:00:00Z",
    "2022-06-23T00:00:00Z"
  ]
]
```

As you can see, I have got a list of list of string. Is there any method of gremlin to help me get whether "2022-06-21T00:00:00Z" is in both of these two list. Of course, "2022-06-21T00:00:00Z" is in ["2022-06-21T00:00:00Z","2022-06-23T00:00:00Z"], but not in ["2022-06-20T00:00:00Z","2022-06-23T00:00:00Z"], so I want the gremlin query return false.

Do you have any suggestions of how to write this gremlin query?
Hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `groupCount` , if the count is 1 it's essentially false, whereas a 2 would mean true.

So for example:

```java
g.inject([["2022-06-21T00:00:00Z","2022-06-23T00:00:00Z"],
 ["2022-06-20T00:00:00Z","2022-06-23T00:00:00Z" ]]).
 unfold().
 unfold().
 groupCount()
```

produces

```
{'2022-06-20T00:00:00Z': 1, '2022-06-23T00:00:00Z': 2, '2022-06-21T00:00:00Z': 1}
```

selecting the specific timestamp

```java
g.inject([["2022-06-21T00:00:00Z","2022-06-23T00:00:00Z"],
 ["2022-06-20T00:00:00Z","2022-06-23T00:00:00Z" ]]).
 unfold().
 unfold().
 groupCount().
 select('2022-06-21T00:00:00Z')
```

produces

```
1
```

To get a true or false response we could further edit the query as follows:

```java
g.inject([["2022-06-21T00:00:00Z","2022-06-23T00:00:00Z"],
 ["2022-06-20T00:00:00Z","2022-06-23T00:00:00Z" ]]).
 unfold().
 unfold().
 groupCount().
 choose(
    select('2022-06-21T00:00:00Z').is(2),constant(true),constant(false))
```

which produces

```
false
```